Conda cannot find a package to install even though I can see it on the anaconda website
I'm trying to install a package through conda. Specifically, the 'dssp' package in the salilab Anaconda channel (https://anaconda.org/salilab/dssp).
After creating and activating a conda environment, I move onto installing my first package. But I get an error saying that Conda the 'dssp' package is not available from the salilab package.
(pymol_env) DESKTOP-108NJBQ:IFN_alpha2a_omega_SASA-main nick$ conda install -c salilab dssp
Channels:
 - salilab
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - dssp

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/salilab
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

This is odd, because I can see the package through anaconda.org.
Can anyone help me figure out what is blocking the installation of dssp in my environment? I have already tried the suggestion from this similar thread (Conda cannot find packages to install) to run conda config --set offline false ;  this did not solve the problem.

You have Platform: osx-arm64, but the package you have linked only has
osx-64
linux-32
linux-64

so conda correctly reports that it cannot find the package, since it cannot install because of the platform mismatch.
A workaround can be to create a x64 environment, as detailed here
